# Can we export json schemas for type script usage?

Tags: entities, javascript

We have a Drupal installation that acts as a backend and a front end that uses the `HttpClientModule` from Angular to query this data.

Thanks to the typescript base, we can provide the functions of this service with the expected return type like `this.httpClient.get<ExpectedTypeInterface>(urlToJsonResource)`. The important question is: Where does the implementation of the `ExpectedTypeInterface` come from?

Wehn I inspect our API via OpenAPI/Swagger UI, I see that there is schema information available. Is there a standard way of exporting this information into typescript interfaces?

Creating them by hand would be a bad choice, because than the front end might get outdated type definitions.

Answer (score -2):

OpenAPI offers an endpoint under `/openapi/rest?_format=json` that delivers the complete json schema.
For the transformation, we need the node package `json-schema-to-typescript`.
This package offers a cli that lets us transform the json schema into a  typescript file.